# SharePoint 2010 - Connecting web parts to metadata navigation in document library

Tags: sharepoint-2010, metadata

Is it possible to read from the SharePOint 2010 metadata navigation in a document library so that the selected value(s) can be passed into another web-part (in this case a CoreResultsWebPart ).

The IsNodeSelected property on the **MetadataNavigationContext** class is reserved for internal use, what is the recommended approach? The metadata navigation does provide a query string in the URL (a very long and complex one) but i'm not sure about trying to de-code this either in case it changes in the next version.

I haven't been able to locate any documentation on how to work with the metadata navigation, any recommendations or links would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Toby

Answer (score 1):

Those query strings aren't encoded, they are the `FieldID` for the `MetadataField`. You could pull the XML for the `MetadataNavigationSettings` or the `Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation` namespace to compare the ID's and find the name of the corresponding metadata field.